# How can i show a modal below another modal in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, modal-dialog, resize, flutter-layout

So, i'm currently developing a "to-do list" app using Flutter. This app has a floating button that, when pressed, shows a modal bottom sheet with a few other buttons. Some of those buttons, when pressed, also returns modal bottom sheets with options for the user to choose from. The thing is, i can't seem to find a way to place the secondary bottom sheet directly below the primary bottom sheet. In other words, i want to make the primary modal resize to avoid being overlapped by the secondary modal. Is that possible on flutter?

Here's what the app should look like

[image: Here's what the app should look like]

And here's what it currently looks like

[image: And here's what it currently looks like]

Here's the code example for the primary modal bottom sheet:

```
taskModal(BuildContext context) {
  return showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(20), topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _buildCancelButton(),
                TaskForm(),
                BuildBorder(),
                PriorityButton(),
                BuildBorder(),
                DateButton(),
                BuildBorder(),
                _buildConfirmButton(context)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

And here is the code example for one of the buttons i've mentioned before (the priority button, specifically):

```
class PriorityButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PriorityButtonState createState() => _PriorityButtonState();
}

class _PriorityButtonState extends State<PriorityButton> {
  
  List<String> _priorities = [
    'Nenhuma',
    'Baixa (!)',
    'Média (!!)',
    'Alta (!!!)',
  ];

  String _settledPriority = 'Selecionar';
   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.flag,
                color: Color(0xff9DA1A6),
              )),
          Text("Prioridade"),
          Expanded(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04),
                child: Text(_settledPriority,
                    maxLines: 1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: () async => await _buildBottomSheet(),
    );
  }

  _setPriority(String priority) {
    setState(() {
      _settledPriority = priority;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }



_buildBottomSheet() {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
            return Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _priorities.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
                  child: Text(
                    _priorities\[index\],
                  ),
                  onTap: () => _setPriority(_priorities\[index\]),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is fetch the height of the bottom modal with [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html), then use this value as padding for the first displayed modal. Though by design, the modal seems to appear in a single [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html). Another approach that you can look into is by populating a single modal instead of using two modal on the screen.